# Only Tokens in Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using JavaScript for parsing a string that looks as follow:

```js
var myString = "unimportant:part.one:unimportant:part.two:unimportant:part.three";
var regex = /\w*:(part.\w*)./gi
```

How can I put only the highlighted part within the parenthesis in an array?

`var myArray = myString.match(regex);` gives me the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern `\w*:(part.\w*).` the leading `\w*` is optional so if you want to match at least a single word character you can just use `\w`

After the capture group there is a dot `.` which matches any character so you will miss the last character at the end of the string as the character is mandatory.

Note to escape the dot `\.` if you want to match it literally

The pattern can look like:

```
\w:(part\.\w+)
```

Then getting the capture group 1 values into an array using `matchAll`

```js
const myString = "unimportant:part.one:unimportant:part.two:unimportant:part.three";
const regex = /\w:(part\.\w+)/gi;
const result = Array.from(myString.matchAll(regex), m => m[1])
console.log(result)
```

Or without a capture group using a lookbehind if that is supported using `match`

```js
const myString = "unimportant:part.one:unimportant:part.two:unimportant:part.three";
const regex = /(?<=\w:)part\.\w+/gi;
console.log(myString.match(regex))
```